# Error with function percentile_disc in Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am currently running the following query in BigQuery:

```
 SELECT
  longTime,
  PERCENTILE_DISC(0.99) OVER (ORDER BY longTime DESC) AS percentil_99,
  cityList
FROM (FLATTEN(FLATTEN([table], longTime), clientId))
WHERE
  cityList IS NOT NULL
  AND clientId='UKTRAR'
  AND bp_Time BETWEEN TIMESTAMP('2015-01-18')
  AND TIMESTAMP('2015-12-18')
```

but when finished displays the following error

```
 Error: Resources exceeded during query execution. 
 Job ID: table:job_Qm_LOGJAFMSXSeXXnVRoLer4C8A
```

the table has the following data

```
Table Size =>   23.4 GB
Number of Rows =>   71,809,730
```

Comment: Is it possible to share the real table name or at least the schema so we can better debug your failure?

The first question I have is, are you certain that both those flatten operations need to be applied before your WHERE clause filter? FLATTEN is an expensive operation and can lead to these resources exceeded error messages.

Another potential source of these failures is the ORDER BY in the window function spec. That has to happen in one worker. Any way to add a PARTITION BY as well?

Comment: The error doesn't necessarily has to do with percentile_disc.... How "flat" is your table? Flatten creates a LOT of rows, depending on how many properties it has to flatten, and how "repeated" the property actually is. If you have 3 longtime AND 3 clientIDs per row... then yeah, you have a LOT more rows than you thought. I'd say we need more info :S.... It's not much, but as a start, look into https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors